# dynamic allcocation object and int c++

Tags: c++, object, integer, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

hello I have a doubt how does the code below works??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* arr = new int;
    arr[0] = 94;
    arr[1] = 4;
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
}
```

and why does this shows me a error what should I do

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test 
{
    int data;
};
int main()
{
    test* arr = new test;
    arr[0] -> data= 4;
    arr[1] -> data= 42;
    cout << arr[0]->data << endl;
}
```

Comment: both variants are undefined behaviour because you're not allocating enough memory for array, you should use `new int[2]` or `new test[2]`

Comment: Applying this to your real code, the answer is _probably_ to use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* arr = new int;
    arr[0] = 94; // This will work
    arr[1] = 4; // This will cause undefined behaviour
    cout << arr[0] << endl;
}
```

Int the above code, `arr` is a pointer to a single `int`, so you can access that one `int` using either:

```
arr[0]
*arr
```

..but arr[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) won't work as there is not enough memory allocated for the array.

To fix this, you must allocate more memory for arr:

```
int* arr = new int[2];
```

..and to change the size of arr:

```
int arr_size = 2;
int* arr = new int[arr_size]; // size of arr = 2
arr[0] = 12;
arr[1] = 13;

int* new_arr = new int[arr_size + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
{
    new_arr[i] = arr[i];
}

delete[] arr;
arr = new_arr;

// size of arr = 3
```

But all of this gets computationally expensive and time-consuming when `arr` has a huge number of elements. So I recommend using `C++`'s `std::vector`:

### Your 2'nd program using `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct test
{
    int data;
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<test> vec{ test(4), test(42) };

    std::cout << vec[0].data << std::endl;
}
```

For more info on `std::vector`, click [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Also, consider not using the following line in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

..as it's considered as bad practice. For more info on this, look up to [why is "using namespace std" considered as bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).